# Access Form Events - What control to use to execute code dynamically

Tags: ms-access-2016

I have created a form to enter training events.
I have an unbound calculated control at the top of my form which reflects the status of the training. Calculated control source:

`=IIf(IsNull([Txt_TrainComm]),"NEW",IIf(IsNull([Txt_TrainComp]),"COMMENCED",IIf(IsNull([txtAssNom]),"ASSESSMENT REQUIRED",IIf(IsNull([txtAssComp]),"ASSESSMENT - NOMINATED","ASSESSED"))))`

My form has a few key dates (Text Box Names: txt_TrainComm, txt_TrainComp, txtAssNom & txtAssComp) to be entered in that order. What I want to happen is as the dates are entered other form controls are enabled, the footer is made visible etc. I have written a code that when placed in the Form Current Event works fine when switching from one record to the next. Please see my code so far below:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()
If Me.StatusName = "NEW" Then
Me.StatusName.Width = 1418
Me.Txt_TrainComp.Enabled = False
Me.Txt_TrainComm.Enabled = True
Me.Page_Assessment.Enabled = False
    If Me.FormFooter.Visible = True Then
    Me.FormFooter.Visible = False
    Me.cmdShowdetails__.Caption = "Show Assessment <<"
    Dim WindowHeightNEW As Long
    WindowHeightNEW = Me.WindowHeight - Me.FormFooter.Height
    Me.Move Left:=Me.WindowLeft, Top:=Me.WindowTop, Height:=WindowHeightNEW
    End If
End If

If Me.StatusName = "COMMENCED" Then
Me.StatusName.Width = 2552
Me.Txt_TrainComp.Enabled = True
Me.Txt_TrainComm.Enabled = True
Me.Page_Assessment.Enabled = False
    If Me.FormFooter.Visible = True Then
    Me.FormFooter.Visible = False
    Me.cmdShowdetails__.Caption = "Show Assessment <<"
    Dim WindowHeightCOMM As Long
    WindowHeightCOMM = Me.WindowHeight - Me.FormFooter.Height
    Me.Move Left:=Me.WindowLeft, Top:=Me.WindowTop, Height:=WindowHeightCOMM
    End If
End If


If Me.StatusName = "ASSESSMENT REQUIRED" Then
Me.StatusName.Width = 4253
Me.Txt_TrainComp.Enabled = True
Me.Txt_TrainComm.Enabled = True
Me.Page_Assessment.Enabled = True
    If Me.FormFooter.Visible = False Then
    Me.FormFooter.Visible = True
    Me.cmdShowdetails__.Caption = "Hide Assessment <<"
    Dim WindowHeightASSREQ As Long
    WindowHeightASSREQ = Me.WindowHeight + Me.FormFooter.Height
    Me.Move Left:=Me.WindowLeft, Top:=Me.WindowTop, Height:=WindowHeightASSREQ
    End If
End If'

If Me.StatusName = "ASSESSMENT - NOMINATED" Then
Me.StatusName.Width = 4925
Me.Txt_TrainComp.Enabled = False
Me.Txt_TrainComm.Enabled = False
Me.Page_Assessment.Enabled = True
    If Me.FormFooter.Visible = False Then
    Me.FormFooter.Visible = True
    Me.cmdShowdetails__.Caption = "Hide Assessment <<"
    Dim WindowHeightASSNOM As Long
    WindowHeightASSNOM = Me.WindowHeight + Me.FormFooter.Height
    Me.Move Left:=Me.WindowLeft, Top:=Me.WindowTop, Height:=WindowHeightASSNOM
    End If
End If


If Me.StatusName = "ASSESSED" Then
Me.StatusName.Width = 1985
Me.Txt_TrainComp.Enabled = False
Me.Txt_TrainComm.Enabled = False
Me.Page_Assessment.Enabled = True
    If Me.FormFooter.Visible = False Then
    Me.FormFooter.Visible = True
    Me.cmdShowdetails__.Caption = "Hide Assessment <<"
    Dim WindowHeightASSD As Long
    WindowHeightASSD = Me.WindowHeight + Me.FormFooter.Height
    Me.Move Left:=Me.WindowLeft, Top:=Me.WindowTop, Height:=WindowHeightASSD
    End If
End If

End Sub
```

What I cant get to work, is placing the code in the correct control event so that for example, when a date is entered into txt_TrainComp, the code is run dynamically. I have to switch to a different record and then back for the changes to take effect which isn't the desired result. I have tried BeforeUpdate, AfterUpdate, OnDirty, OnChange and they dont seem to work.

Is someone able to please have a look and make a suggestion to what event or code changes I need to make? Hopefully I have provided enough information.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: FormObject_LostFocus()

Comment: Hello @RetiredGeek. Thank you for your response. That seems to have worked. I created a sub not tied into an event titled FormUpdate () and then copied the code into that. I then created a LostFocus Event for each of the controls which then call that Sub. It probably isnt the most elegant solution but it seems to work exactly as i intended. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to RetiredGeek, FormObject_LostFocus() was the correct event to run the code after focus is changed.

```
Private Sub Txt_TrainComm_LostFocus()
Call FormUpdate
Me.TrainingStatus.Value = Me.StatusName
End Sub

Private Sub Txt_TrainComp_LostFocus()
Call FormUpdate
Me.TrainingStatus.Value = Me.StatusName
End Sub

Private Sub txtAssComp_LostFocus()
Call FormUpdate
Me.TrainingStatus.Value = Me.StatusName
End Sub

Private Sub txtAssNom_LostFocus()
Call FormUpdate
Me.TrainingStatus.Value = Me.StatusName
End Sub
```